# Cyclic Dependency Issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have a three way cyclic dependency between three header files, each of which has one class within it. This is the relevant portion of the `Agent2` class:

```
#ifndef BUYINGJEANS1_H
#define BUYINGJEANS1_H
class Agent2{
    public:
    Agent2(){}

    double getAdvertisingFash(int currentTime, int sFash, int brand){
        Agent1 agent1;
        Agent3 agent3;
        double probabilityOfChangingFashion = (exp((-advertisementArray[currentTime+1][brand]*pow(abs(min(fashionArray[brand]+1,4.0)-sFash),D))+(-alphaArray[2][2]*pow(abs(fashionArray[brand]-sFash),AArray[2][2]))) * (exp((-(agent1.alphaArray[2][1])*pow(abs((agent1.fashionArray[brand])-sFash),AArray[2][1]))))*(exp((-(agent3.alphaArray[2][3])*pow(abs((agent3.fashionArray[brand])-sFash),AArray[2][3])))))/getZScoreAdvertisingFash(currentTime,brand);
        return probabilityOfChangingFashion;
    }
#endif
```

An equivalent function exists in the `Agent1` and `Agent3` classes, except `Agent1` would use `Agent2` and `Agent3`, and `Agent3` would use `Agent1` and `Agent2`.

I know that forward declaration won't work here because I obviously need to use the members of classes `Agent2` and `Agent3`. When I run a main function in a separate cpp file that uses this code, I receive an undeclared identifier error for `Agent1` and `Agent3`.

Anyone know how I can resolve this in the simplest manner possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to move the body of one or more of your functions into a `.cpp` file instead of the header. This way, `Agent1` and `Agent3` can include the `Agent2` header without the `Agent2` header needing them.

You only need to move the implementation of the functions of one of these classes to break the cyclic dependency, but you  may want to do it for all three to be consistent and avoid similar problems in the future.

In Agent2.H:

```
#ifndef BUYINGJEANS1_H
#define BUYINGJEANS1_H
class Agent2{
    public:
    Agent2(){}

    double getAdvertisingFash(int currentTime, int sFash, int brand);
}
#endif
```

And in Agent2.cpp:

```
#include "Agent2.H"

#include "Agent1.H"
#include "Agent3.H"
double Agent2::getAdvertisingFash(int currentTime, int sFash, int brand)
{
    Agent1 agent1;
    Agent3 agent3;
    double probabilityOfChangingFashion = (exp((-advertisementArray[currentTime+1][brand]*pow(abs(min(fashionArray[brand]+1,4.0)-sFash),D))+(-alphaArray[2][2]*pow(abs(fashionArray[brand]-sFash),AArray[2][2]))) * (exp((-(agent1.alphaArray[2][1])*pow(abs((agent1.fashionArray[brand])-sFash),AArray[2][1]))))*(exp((-(agent3.alphaArray[2][3])*pow(abs((agent3.fashionArray[brand])-sFash),AArray[2][3])))))/getZScoreAdvertisingFash(currentTime,brand);
    return probabilityOfChangingFashion;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the member function definitions to separate .cpp files and include the header there.

Something like this:

```
#include "agent2.hpp"

double Agent2::getAdvertisingFash(int currentTime, int sFash, int brand){
    Agent1 agent1;
    Agent3 agent3;
    double probabilityOfChangingFashion = (exp((-advertisementArray[currentTime+1][brand]*pow(abs(min(fashionArray[brand]+1,4.0)-sFash),D))+(-alphaArray[2][2]*pow(abs(fashionArray[brand]-sFash),AArray[2][2]))) * (exp((-(agent1.alphaArray[2][1])*pow(abs((agent1.fashionArray[brand])-sFash),AArray[2][1]))))*(exp((-(agent3.alphaArray[2][3])*pow(abs((agent3.fashionArray[brand])-sFash),AArray[2][3])))))/getZScoreAdvertisingFash(currentTime,brand);
    return probabilityOfChangingFashion;
}
```